# Usage of word carriage for taxi

Tags: word-usage

> > Can we say that as compared to train a taxi has only one **carriage**?

I checked the meaning of **"carriage"** in [Oxford](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/carriage) and [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/carriage), but I didn't find any such meaning. However, I found that it is being used in such a manner in many places.

For example, it is used in this way as mentioned on [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxicab) page of Wikipedia:

> > In the same year in New York City, the Samuel's Electric Carriage and Wagon Company began running 12 electric hansom cabs.

Do we have any other replacement of **"carriage"** here, which is more suitable in this context?

Comment: Perhaps you're better off with the word **compartment** or the phrase **passenger compartment**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A *taxicab* is by definition a single automobile, so there is no need to suggest there is only one.

Larger vehicles that serve a similar function have different names like "bus", "trolley", "subway", "train", etc.  These can have more than one *car*.

Trains and subways will sometimes call a "car" a "carriage", especially in BrE, but when used for single vehicles *carriage* refers to an older, horse-drawn vehicle.

(Edit) Please see the other answer for images commonly associated with *carriage*.  Also, even though it's not part of the dictionary definition, it's possible that a carriage is a four-wheeled conveyance which does not move under its own power.  For example, it is the *locomotive* which drives the train, and pulls (and/or pushes) a series of *carriages*.  Similarly  there still exist *horse-drawn* carriages, usually as a novelty.

The exception being the "electric carriage", pictured in the other answer, since replaced by the *automobile*.

(Side note) Like *taxi*, *carriage* implies a vehicle used to move people, not cargo.  For a cargo-bearing vehicle pulled by draft animals, there is *cart*, *wagon*, or (in special cases) *caravan*, or (more archaic and obscure) *dray, wain, or caisson*.

Answer (score 2):

You're confusing two different meanings of the word *carriage*:

> 6a) a wheeled vehicle; especially : a horse-drawn vehicle designed for private use and comfort
>
> 6b) British : a railway passenger coach

(per [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/carriage)).

A cab does not *have* a carriage (in either sense of the word) - but cabs used to *be* carriages. Specifically, the quote you've brought up mentions **electric carriages**:

[image: https://i.pinimg.com/564x/4a/b9/fa/4ab9faa6e5764dd22a350b48536664fd--electric-cars-woods.jpg]

named so due to their similarity to actual, horse drawn carriages (which were also used as cabs before the invention of an automobile):

[image: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c9/HansomCab.jpg]

You wouldn't, however, call a contemporary taxi car a *carriage* - or say that it has one. And none of it has anything to do with actual train carriages:

[image: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/71/158A_Train_Carriage.jpg/1200px-158A_Train_Carriage.jpg]

Comment: Both are right answers mentioning different information. I wish I could make both as accepted answers.